# Ajax click event only working once

Tags: ajax, click

Hello I am going insane with Ajax, I am just a novice with this....

I have a simple table with records....each record can be activated and deactivated...

Activate calls this ajax code:

```
$('#activate').click(function() {  
    var $this = $(this);
    var p1 = $this.data('p1'); 
    var p2 = $this.data('p2');
    $.ajax({                                                        
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/admin/registrations/activate";?>       /'+p1,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,  
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == 1) {         
                $("#entry"+p1).html("<a id='deactivate' href='javascript:;'     data-p1='"+p1+"' data-p2='"+p2+"'>Deactivate</a>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

While the Deactivate event calls this other Ajax code:

```
$('#deactivate').click(function(){  
        var $this = $(this);
        var p1 = $this.data('p1');
        var p2 = $this.data('p2');
         $.ajax({                                                        
            url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/admin/registrations/deactivate";?>/'+p1,
            type: "GET", 
            cache: false,    
            success: function(response) {  
                if(response == 0){ 
                    $("#entry"+p1).html("<a id='activate' href='javascript:;' data-p1='"+p1+"' data-p2='"+p2+"'>Activate</a>"); 
                }                                   
            }                   
        });                                                               
    });
```

Once the Activate turns into Deactivate....the Deactivate link doesnt work and viceversa...
so the link only works once...

How can i fix this?
I appreciate your help

Comment: When you update your html call the function again

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .on() to bind the events to your links.  Using $('#deactivate').click(...) only binds to elements which are present in the DOM at the time of the call.  By using .on() you bind to current and future elements.

The link you are inserting with this statement: `$("#entry"+p1).html("<a id='activate'` is therefore not being bound to the click event at all and that's why nothing happens when you click it.

See here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Update**

Here's a Codepen which shows how .on() can be used to bind to current and future elements:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypvuh

Notice how new links that are created and inserted into the DOM when the "Add new link" button is clicked are also bound to the click event.

So in your case, your code should look something like this:

```
$('body').on('click','#activate',function() {  
    var $this = $(this);
    var p1 = $this.data('p1'); 
    var p2 = $this.data('p2');
    $.ajax({                                                        
        url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/admin/registrations/activate";?>       /'+p1,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,  
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == 1) {         
                $("#entry"+p1).html("<a id='deactivate' href='javascript:;'     data-p1='"+p1+"' data-p2='"+p2+"'>Deactivate</a>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
$('body').on('click','#deactivate',function() {    
        var $this = $(this);
        var p1 = $this.data('p1');
        var p2 = $this.data('p2');
         $.ajax({                                                        
            url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/admin/registrations/deactivate";?>/'+p1,
            type: "GET", 
            cache: false,    
            success: function(response) {  
                if(response == 0){ 
                    $("#entry"+p1).html("<a id='activate' href='javascript:;' data-p1='"+p1+"' data-p2='"+p2+"'>Activate</a>"); 
                }                                   
            }                   
        });                                                               
    });
```

Note, since ID's are supposed to be unique within a page, I'd consider giving the links a class attribute of "activate" and "deactivate", otherwise you are probably ending up with multiple links on the page with the same ID.  If you do change it, also make sure to change the selector in the .on() binding.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but would you kindly show me how to do that?

Comment: Can someone explain to me how to rewrite my ajax call with .on ? please?

Comment: Gimme 20 minutes, not at my computer at the mo